# What shoud be the sans font for NewTX in math mode?

Tags: sans-serif, newtxmath, computer-modern, newtx

Related to [How to reduce the height of the capitals in the sans math font in newtx version ≥ 1.724?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708722):

Running `pdflatex` followed by `pdffonts` on

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{newtx}%% uses CM Super for math sans
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}%% uses TeX Gyre Heros for math sans
\begin{document}
$\mathsf{X}$
\end{document}
```

yields

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
TETOMV+TeXGyreHeros-Regular          Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes      4  0
```

whereas running `pdflatex` followed by `pdffonts` on

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtx}%% uses CM Super for math sans
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}%% uses TeX Gyre Heros for math sans
\begin{document}
$\mathsf{X}$
\end{document}
```

yields

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
WZFWLE+SFSS1000                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes      4  0
```

On my system, SFSS1000 in located in the directories for cm-super. However, NewTX documentation as of 2024-01-10 is silent about Computer Modern Sans for the input above, only stating “Option nohelv prevents loading TeXGyreHeros, leaving cmss as the default sans font.” in § 3 on p. 9, l. 5.  So is loading *Computer Modern Super* an intentional (and undocumented) behavior for the new interface `\usepackage{newtx}` or just a bug?

Comment: Please address the question "So is loading Computer Modern Super an intentional (and undocumented) behavior for the new interface `\usepackage{newtx}` or just a bug?" to Michael Sharpe, the creator and maintainer of the [newtx](https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx) package. He, and he alone, is in a position to answer this question.

Comment: @Mico I've already done so. And as we're not perfect, there's always a small possibility the we've overlooked some piece of documentation already present.

Comment: Whichever you like. This depends on individual tastes.