# The order of loading newtxtext, newtxmath and mathtools?

Tags: mathtools, newtxmath

The *newtxmath* documentation says that it loads amsmath now. However, mathtools also loads amsmath. What should the order of the packages better be then:

```latex
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

or

```latex
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

?

(So far, I've been loading mathtools last, but my texts are big, so small changes/errors during updates/upgrades sometimes go unnoticed.)
We may safely assume that the user passes some options to all of the three packages.

Comment: you can use `newtx` which will load newtxtext and newtxmath and can load mathtools before or after that

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Except that loading newtx has some unexpected effects: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708722/how-to-reduce-the-height-of-the-capitals-in-the-sans-math-font-in-newtx-version

Comment: yes I saw your other questions later, maybe you should report to get some of those changed, but anyway have you any reason to suspect order matters at all here?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I cannot give a provide us with a particular, specific reason here and now. § 9 of NewTX documentation prescribes a particular order if amsthm is also present. In my own documents without amsthm, I've been loading mathtools last and working around other font issues (which are likely to be unrelated, but you never know — the real reasons are often surprising …).

Comment: Reading through the newtx package, I would load it last, but here what I suggest. First mathtools, Iassume you need some  of its features, then newtxtmath. But the elephants in the room will be babel and fontspec as well and the class you use. Make a MWE using the amsart class and test some of the maths you using. For example mathtools allows you to create new delims. After you have done this change amsart to article and retest with LuaLaTeX.